# Accessing an sqlite3 file with Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, sqlite

I'm doing the second part of Ray Wenderlich's Core Data Tutorial. Instead of reading the file that contains the default data, I'm trying to read the actual Failed Bank datafile that was created in his SQLite3 tutorial.  The program is throwing an exception when I try to create the Store and open the File.

Here is the code snippet

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) persistentStoreCoordinator
{

    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"banklist.sqlite3"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {

    NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banklist" ofType:@"sqlite3"]];
    NSError *err = nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"Opps, couldn't copy preloaded data");
    }
}

NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

Here is the exception:

2013-09-16 20:19:57.549 FailedBankCD[4086:c07] CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /Users/artletter1/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/524B84E3-94D6-40A3-8847-DD15A99B22A2/Documents/banklist.sqlite3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA'
2013-09-16 20:19:57.552 FailedBankCD[4086:c07] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x854b560 {NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at /Users/artletter1/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/524B84E3-94D6-40A3-8847-DD15A99B22A2/Documents/banklist.sqlite3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA', NSSQLiteErrorDomain=1}, {
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 1;
    NSUnderlyingException = "I/O error for database at /Users/artletter1/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/524B84E3-94D6-40A3-8847-DD15A99B22A2/Documents/banklist.sqlite3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA'";
}

Thanks!

Roy

Comment: It would help if you actually linked to what you're trying to work on. But, by the looks of it your database doesn't contain the Z_METADATA table which Core Data will require. You can't just hook up any sqlite database to Core Data you know...

Comment: Exactly, you need the tables and columns that Core Data expects.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you intend to do you will have to go through the tables of your sqlite file using the sqlite3 API, insert new Core Data entities, fill them with the data and save to a different file.
.